# I would like to know how to execute a command from the acquiring of advancement zombie doctor

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I would like to run an execute command from a players acquiring of the zombies doctor advancement and there distance to the detecting repeating command block.

```
execute if entity @p[distance=1..,advancements={zombie_doctor=true}] run...
```

This isn't working however reads ok in the block and I've tried various variants of the namespace id.
such as story/cure_zombie_villager etc..

Comment: The second one ("`story/cure_zombie_villager`") works for me. But of course only if you're 1 block or more away from the command block and have the advancement.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for the test appreciated. It was a syntax error on my behalf may of taken a while to circle back around Without the hint. I used "DOCTOR" instead of "VILLAGER" and the solution was a quick fix from there once it was noticed.

What's I was using
execute if entity @p[distance=.. 10,advancements={story/cure_zombie_doctor=true} run....

Comment: Can you specify what the syntax error was, so this answer might help other users? (And why did you make another account?)

Comment: You seem to be using a different account from the one you used to ask the question. See https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts on how to merge your two accounts.